# Cant pass params id in vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

Please tell me how instead of {id} when getter call, take its id and insert it into the link with the request in vuex

industry.js

```
 import { INDUSTRY } from '@/utils/store/getters.names.js'
        import { FETCH_INDUSTRY } from '@/utils/store/actions.names.js'
        import { SET_INDUSTRY, SET_INDUSTRY_ERROR } from '@/utils/store/mutations.names.js'
        import { API_ENDPOINT } from '@/utils/store/endpoints.js'
        
        export const state = () => ({
          industry: [],
          industryError: false
        })
        
        export const getters = {
          [INDUSTRY]: state => state.industry
        }
        export const actions = {
          [FETCH_INDUSTRY] ({ commit }, id) {
        
            this.$axios.$get(`${API_ENDPOINT}/pages/?child_of=${id}&type=pages.IndustryEquipmentCategoryPage&fields=*`).then((data) => {
              commit(SET_INDUSTRY, data)
            }).catch((e) => {
              commit(SET_INDUSTRY_ERROR)
            })
          }
        }
        
        export const mutations = {
          [SET_INDUSTRY] (state, industry) {
            state.industryError = false
            state.industry = industry
          },
        
          [SET_INDUSTRY_ERROR] (state) {
            state.industry = []
            state.industryError = true
          }
        }
```

index.js

```
import { FETCH_MENU, FETCH_SETTINGS, FETCH_INDUSTRY } from '@/utils/store/actions.names.js'

export const state = () => ({})
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit ({ dispatch }) {
    dispatch(`menu/${FETCH_MENU}`)
    dispatch(`settings/${FETCH_SETTINGS}`)
    dispatch(`industry/${FETCH_INDUSTRY}`)
  }
}
```

actions.names.js

```
export const FETCH_INDUSTRY = 'fetchIndustry'
```

getters.names.js

```
export const INDUSTRY = 'industry'
```

mutations.names.js

```
export const SET_INDUSTRY = 'setIndustry'
export const SET_INDUSTRY_ERROR = 'SetIndustryError'
```

i cannot pass id to fetch getter data. how can i pass params id in getters please tell me
IndustryEquipmentIndexPage.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="eqmodel-mainwrap">
    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {
  Component,
  Getter,
  Prop,
  Action,
  Mutation,
  Vue,
  mixins,
  Watch
} from "nuxt-property-decorator";
import { PhCaretRight, PhCaretLeft } from "phosphor-vue";
import { INDUSTRY } from "~/utils/store/getters.names";
import { FETCH_INDUSTRY } from "~/utils/store/actions.names";
import { SET_INDUSTRY,SET_INDUSTRY_ERROR } from "~/utils/store/mutations.names";
import { PAGES_ENDPOINT } from "@/utils/store/endpoints.js";
import { gsap, TimelineMax, Power2, Power1, clearProps } from "gsap/all";
import axios from "axios";
import { directive } from "vue-awesome-swiper";

@Component({
  name: "IndustryEquipmentIndexPage",
  components: {
    PhCaretRight,
    PhCaretLeft
  }
})
export default class IndustryEquipmentIndexPage extends Vue {
  @Prop() pageData;
   @Action(FETCH_INDUSTRY) fetchIndustry;
  @Mutation(SET_INDUSTRY) setIndustry;
  @Getter(`industry/${INDUSTRY}`) industry;
   
   
  get HOST() {
    return process.env.HOST;
  }
  
  
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you getting your id from? Where do you have it available?

Comment: i wanted to pass param child_of=${id}  to getter this.$store.dispatch('FETCH_INDUSTRY', { id: this.Pagedata.id }) but i cannot fecth data

Comment: You're calling `dispatch(FETCH_INDUSTRY)` without any payload, so `id` would be `undefined` in your action.

Answer (score 1):

According to Vue documentation you can do that with [method style access.](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access)

```
    export const getters = {
      [INDUSTRY]: state => (id) => state.industry.find(smthg => smthg.id === id)
    }
```